# /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset.cpus Not Found After Enabling Privileged Mode In Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, privileges, cgroups, containerd, cpuset

I am currently running into an issue where /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset.cpus is no longer present in my Kubernetes Pod when I enable Privileged mode.
For example:
I start off with a very simple pod spec (`test.yaml`):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-0
spec:
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/hostname: "node1"
  containers:
    - name: pod-0
      image: ubuntu:22.04
      command: [ "/bin/sh" , "-c", "tail -f /dev/null" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 4
          memory: 2Gi
        limits:
          cpu: 4
          memory: 2Gi
```

I start the pod and exec into it:

```bash
kubectl apply -f test.yaml 
kubectl exec -it test-0 -- /bin/bash
```

Once in the container, I run the following:

```bash
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset.cpus
```

The output is `44,46,100,102` i.e the cpus allocated to my pod are printed as expected using  cgroupv2 filesystem

Next I remove the pod (`kubectl delete pod test-0`) and create a new pod with the following spec (note the new privileged securityContext):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-0
spec:
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/hostname: "node1"
  containers:
    - name: pod-0
      image: ubuntu:22.04
      securityContext:
        allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
        privileged: true
      command: [ "/bin/sh" , "-c", "tail -f /dev/null" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 4
          memory: 2Gi
        limits:
          cpu: 4
          memory: 2Gi
```

Same as before, I start the pod and exec into it:

```bash
kubectl apply -f test.yaml 
kubectl exec -it test-0 -- /bin/bash
```

Again, once in the container, I run the following:

```bash
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset.cpus
```

But this time I get the following error:

```
cat: /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset.cpus: No such file or directory
```

Why is this happening whereby adding privileges to my container, it removes the /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset.cpus file from my container in Kubernetes?

**Kubernetes Version:** 1.26.2

**Cgroup driver:** systemd

**Containerd Version:** 1.6.20

**OS Version:** Ubuntu 22.04.2

**Kernel:** 5.15.0-76-generic

Comment: Why does this matter?  How does your application use this particular setting?

Comment: My application here is DPDK and we read from that file to understand the cpu ids that have been assigned to my pod which DPDK can then run on

Answer (score 0):

With `privileged` being enabled, the cgroup directory of the host will be mounted into the container instead of the container's own cgroup hierarchy.
if you wish to view only your container's CPU stats, you should not enable privileged for your pod